# Fantasy book series, daughter of the "forest god"

Tags: story-identification

I’m looking for a fantasy book series I read in the ’90s or early 2000s in German, but I think it was a translation from English. I don’t remember much.

One of the protagonists is a girl, and she is the daughter of a powerful forest god (a centaur/half deer/something like that) in disguise.

I only remember a scene about a battle or raid on a village, where some kids took shelter in an oven and the attacker starts the oven and kills the kids.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/54017820-little-thieves has Ragne, daughter of a forest god, but it's from 2021.

Comment: sorry, defenitely, I read it while in school and got it from the best fantasy/sciFi dealer on the planet, Hermke. So back in the good old days, end of the millenium/start of the new.